# socket = new Socket(serverAddr, PORT);

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

**When I say socket =  new Socket(serverAddr, PORT); in android, what type of socket is opened? UDP socket or TCP Socket?**

I am trying to send the data from my android and reading it from my PC. I am reading it from UDP receiver C# script(Unity3D). But my android reports Connection timed out exception.

My question is, what type of socket does android open?

Comment: `Socket.connect` opens a TCP socket

To use UDP, you need to create a `DatagramSocket`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I was trying to read the accelerometer data on my phone from my pc in real-time. I opened a tcp connection to get the data stream over WiFi . But there is some lag. What is a better way to do this? Is wifi the right method,or should I try Bluetooth? Ultimately my phone should transmit data like a wireless mouse.

Answer (score -1):

you used from tcp. for using udp socket using below sample code :

**Server code** :

```
public class udp_server
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    DatagramSocket sock = null;

    try
    {
        //1. creating a server socket, parameter is local port number
        sock = new DatagramSocket(7777);

        //buffer to receive incoming data
        byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
        DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

        //2. Wait for an incoming data
        echo("Server socket created. Waiting for incoming data...");

        //communication loop
        while(true)
        {
            sock.receive(incoming);
            byte[] data = incoming.getData();
            String s = new String(data, 0, incoming.getLength());

            //echo the details of incoming data - client ip : client port - client message
            echo(incoming.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " : " + incoming.getPort() + " - " + s);

            s = "OK : " + s;
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(s.getBytes() , s.getBytes().length , incoming.getAddress() , incoming.getPort());
            sock.send(dp);
        }
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("IOException " + e);
    }
}

//simple function to echo data to terminal
public static void echo(String msg)
{
    System.out.println(msg);
}
}
```

**Client Code** :

```
public class udp_client
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    DatagramSocket sock = null;
    int port = 7777;
    String s;

    BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try
    {
        sock = new DatagramSocket();

        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

        while(true)
        {
            //take input and send the packet
            echo("Enter message to send : ");
            s = (String)cin.readLine();
            byte[] b = s.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket  dp = new DatagramPacket(b , b.length , host , port);
            sock.send(dp);

            //now receive reply
            //buffer to receive incoming data
            byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
            DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            sock.receive(reply);

            byte[] data = reply.getData();
            s = new String(data, 0, reply.getLength());

            //echo the details of incoming data - client ip : client port -     client message
            echo(reply.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " : " +         reply.getPort() + " - " + s);
        }
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("IOException " + e);
    }
}

//simple function to echo data to terminal
public static void echo(String msg)
{
    System.out.println(msg);
}
}
```